# How Limit Download in Windows Server For Users ? ( like Apache )

Tags: windows, apache, limit

In Apache ( Linux Server ) For Limit Download For Users , I Use Below Code :

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Test"
AuthUserFile "users.txt"
require valid-user
```

How Limit Users in Windows Server by TXT file ?